# select from predefined list if exist ,else insert a new item to the list?

Tags: usability, forms, interaction-design, layout, accessibility

What's the best experience to do the following:

The user will insert a new subject(text) only if it isn't in the existing list. So, it will be added to the existing list for all users.

I have implemented this with the following sequence:

[image: Form field - text input field with drop down arrow]

If the user can't find the subject, then they click on the plus (+) button:

[image: Added new text input field with no drop down]

After typing in the new field, clicking the plus (+) button will add it to the list and select it.

Is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The **most common implementation of such a feature  which I see everyday is the tagging system**. As you continue typing, the ajax search is on and you can see results popping up.

Img 1: You can **select from the results** or type in the entire thing.

Img 2: Or, you can **add your own tag** in a similar manner and it will accept the tag and add it in the system for anyone to use.

Img 1:
[image]

Img 2:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

By **adding the + sign, it is counter intuitive** as the user would have to click the drop down, read through the options and determine none of the options listed apply. Then click the + and provide the value.

I would **suggest adding a 'Other' or 'add new' entry in the drop down list**.  This would mean that the user would scan the list of drop down items, find that none apply and select the 'Other'/'Add new' entry.

When this value is selected, then the text box is made visible and given focus allowing the users to provide the value details.

Comment: Other/add new is definitely good, this could be useful when selecting from a drop down, or when typing something in, as the drop down could display search matches, with the top match being Create "your_search_entry".

Answer (score 3):

I would use a **drop down with auto-correct showing the existing alternatives, while the user is typing** - and they could select from that drop down or create their own... depending how much you want them to pay attention to first trying to select an existing alternative.

I like the tagging idea from RK as well